# Unable to find page objects section,what am I missing here?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Using Nightwatch's Page Object capability, I have a page of nesting page object sections. When  I run the test 'googleCase.js'

This is the error I'm getting:
`Error: Element "appSection" was not found in "menu". Available elements: mail, images`

> environment :nightwatch v1.3.2

Code sample：

My page： google.js

```
module.exports = {
    url: 'https://google.com',
    sections: {
        menu: {
            selector: '#gb',
            elements: {
                mail: {
                    selector: 'a[href="mail"]'
                },
                images: {
                    selector: 'a[href="imghp"]'
                }
            },
            sections: {
                apps: {
                    selector: 'div.gb_pc',
                    elements: {
                        myAccount: {
                            selector: '#gb192'
                        },
                        googlePlus: {
                            selector: '#gb119'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

test: googleCase.js

```
module.exports = {
    'Test' : function (browser) {
        let google = browser.page.google();
        google.navigate()
        google.expect.section('@menu').to.be.visible;


        var menuSection = google.section.menu;
        var appSection = menuSection.section.apps;
        menuSection.click('@appSection');

        browser.end()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the syntax you are using is wrong,
> check [nightwatch-api]: https://nightwatchjs.org/api/pageobject/
>
> it should be

```
url:{
},elements:{
},commands:[]
```

> if you want to use custom functions use commands section. in elements section we can >specify only the widget details